# Brand new react native app fails on run-ios xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode8, react-native-ios

I just created a new React Native app using their CLI interface and it fails without making any changes. I first noticed this when I tried to use `version 0.45.1`, it still seems to be happening in `version 0.46.1`

My current version that came with the CLI install.

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
"react-native": "0.46.1"
```

The last time I was able to successfully run an app was back on `version 0.44.3`

I've tried running

`watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
npm install`

But it doesn't help. Full error message below.

`CompileC /Users/brianclarke/Documents/development/ShitProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Conv.o /Users/brianclarke/Documents/development/ShitProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/Conv.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)`

`Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShitProject.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`

`Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShitProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`

EDIT:

I couldn't figure it out, so I completely reinstalled my OS and everything works fine. Obviously that's not a fix, but felt it was worth sharing.