# Can't run a react native app with XCode 8.3

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm struggling to run a fresh react-native project on ios, I have an old Xcode vs (8.13.0), my mac it is also old (10.13.0), so I can't update Xcode to vs 12+ either my mac to 10.15+

I do not believe this question is a duplex from the below links, is about trying to make it work with what I have, if there is any way

[Where can I download old versions of Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047735/where-can-i-download-old-versions-of-xcode)

[Where can I download old versions of Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047735/where-can-i-download-old-versions-of-xcode/46652775#46652775)

[Brand new react native app fails on run-ios xcode 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999155/brand-new-react-native-app-fails-on-run-ios-xcode-8-3)

Xcode 8.3
R.N 0.63.4

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use RN 0.53.x for Xcode 8.3.3 instead. This would limit you from utilising a lot of 3rd party libraries such as React Native Elements.

Starting from RN 0.54, you have to use Xcode 9 or upper.